# NSAttributedString / NSTextTab Alignment Issue

Tags: cocoa, text, formatting, spacing, nsattributedstring

### GOAL:

I'm attempting to use NSAttributedStrings (in conjunction with NSTextTabs) to create the following layout:

```
[ Title           # ]  <-- Useable in NSTableViews, NSMenuItems, etc.
[ Another Title   # ]
[ T3              # ]
```

### ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:

The code I'm attempting is:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *tabStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[tabStyle setTabStops: [NSArray array]];
[tabStyle addTabStop: [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithType: NSRightTabStopType location: 200.0]];
[attrString appendAttributedString: [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"\t"]];
[attrString addAttribute: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: tabStyle range: NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length])];
[attrString appendAttributedString: [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"1"]];
```

Where `attrString` is an NSMutableAttributeString, currently set to the "Title".

However, using this code (which I would assume would produce the desired output), produces the following:

[image: Screenshot - NSTextTabs]

### FURTHER INFORMATION:

When I remove the references to NSTextTabs, like so:

```
[attrString appendAttributedString: [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"\t"]];
[attrString appendAttributedString: [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"1"]];
```

I get the expected output of uneven tabbing.

[image: Screenshot - No NSTexTabs]

### BOTTOM LINE:

Why is the NSAttributedString seemingly ignoring the NSParagraphStyle/NSTextTabs?

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue, by making an NSTextView in IB and placing the AttributedString into it.

[image]

Apparently, the layout needs to be "Scrolls" (was "Truncates") in order to produce the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you! Been tearing my hair out about this one!